# How to Mount a Linux directory from a different PC to your local Linux PC?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

Is there a way to mount a Linux directory from a different PC to your local Linux PC? How?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's called [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_file_system).  You might also want to check out [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) which is pretty nice.

Answer (score 39):

sshfs is very nice, and easy to use

```
sshfs user@remotesystem:/remote/dir /some/local/dir
```

Comment: Much simpler solution, especially for quick tasks. Something not clearly documented: -o ro will mount the file system readonly.

Comment: Adding "-C" switch will enable compression and can greatly increase transfer speeds - in my case a 8 fold improvement.

Comment: If the SSH connection drops for any reason you may lose your data. Hence,you’d want to save your work regularly as you work on files within an SSHFS mount.

Answer (score 12):

You need to be a bit more specific.  You can use NFS.

Depending on what distro you're using, you simply edit the `/etc/exports` file on the remote machine to export the directories you want, then start your NFS daemon.

Then on the local PC, you mount it using the following command:

```
mount -t nfs {remote_pc_address}:/remote/dir /some/local/dir
```

Use the `man` utility for more information:

**man exports** *(Examples of configuring directories for export are on the bottom of this manual page.)*

Comment: Why do I need to "export" the directory from the remote machine? Why isn't `mount -t nfs {remote_pc_address}:/remote/dir /some/local/dir` from the local machine enough?

Answer (score 5):

NFS is handy since it's built-in and easy to configure, but the 2 common implementations (NFSv2 and NFSv3) don't translate usernames between the systems; user IDs are used instead. This requires you to use a central auth system such as LDAP so tha tcommon user IDs can be maintained.

sshfs requires you to connect as a single user and so accesses are always done (and consequently, can only be done) as that user.

cifs in a *nix-to-*nix connection (via Samba) both translates usernames *and* follows standard *nix permissions. As well, it is more flexible in that it allows you to perform ownership/permission transformation on creation of a new file or directory. It is, however, much more complex to configure.

Comment: Is NFS still blocking you 100% if the remote computer is not available for whatever reason?

Answer (score 1):

sshfs works pretty well for me.

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other root@1.2.3.4:/directory local_directory
```

remote machine ip : 1.2.3.4